# How to remove all the Pink Numbers That Show Up When Using Move Tool On Type & Vector Graphics

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, typesetting

Hello I was trying to change the size of shape layer and type but a bunch of numbers keep showing up that's really getting on nerves. Im not sure what to call all of these numbers. If anyone has any idea remove all of the numbers seen on the screenshot below please let me know. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Those are generated by the Smart Guides functionality. To switch Smart Guides off do *View > Show*, then uncheck *Smart Guides*.

Comment: Should be an answer @BillyKerr `:)` Not sure what else anyone could post about it

Comment: @Scott - OK, added as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Those are generated by the Smart Guides functionality. To switch Smart Guides off do *View > Show*, then uncheck *Smart Guides*

Comment: .. could also untick just the labels in the smart guides preferences.